# How to host React app on godday which is configured with webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-redux, web-hosting, godaddy-api

I want to host a react app on my godaddy server. I'm able to run webpack dev server locally, but I don't know how to host it on my godaddy cpanel server.

Link to my code: https://bitbucket.org/touristtribe/tribe-frontend/src/master/

Answer (score 2):

In case you're using create-react-app, you get a script to build your production app, `npm run build`

This builds a folder with all the necessary html,css and js files called `build`. But when you're hosting in an apache server, you'll always need a `.htaccess` file. So first create this file in the `public` folder and then run the build command. The code that goes in the `.htaccess` file is

`Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]`

Moreover, if you're deploying to any subdirectory, you'll have to specify that in the `package.json` file as:
`"homepage": "http://mywebsite.com/relativepath"`

You can read more in this [blog](http://jinsoft.in/host-react-app-on-shared-cpanel-hosting/).

Note: This answer might only help if you're using create-react-app.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, why are you using jQuery with React?  This is not recommended.

You'll first need to build your project.
For Example, if you have `yarn`, simply execute `yarn build` in your terminal.
It will return a build folder that includes an `.html` file and other folders/files.

Then all you need to do is upload those files/folders to your host.